# Remove vertex while using knife tool?

Tags: modeling, mesh, knife-tool

When using the knife tool, if I accidentally click in the wrong spot, is there a way to remove the last placed vertex instead of cancelling the whole operation and starting over?

Comment: Excellent question, unfortunately there is no way to do so at the moment.

Comment: Dang, I hope they implement that eventually. Doesn't seem too complicated to add and it would be pretty useful. Thanks :)

Comment: Another tool you might want to take a look at it is the [*Vertex Connect*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Vertex_Connect) tool (J). It's a little similar to the knife tool, but it's not a modal operator. In some situations I prefer using it to the knife tool.

Comment: I'll take a look at it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The knife tool has no undo support.
While it is possible to have undo history in a modal operator tool, at this time the knife tool does not. Nor is adding undo functionality planned.

However after confirming the knife tool cut, there are other modeling tools that can help you get around a misplaced vertex.

- <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Vertices*, that will delete the selected vertex, or vertices and fill the surrounding geometry.
- <kbd>V</kbd> if you accidentally snapped the vertex to a vertex already on the model, then you can [rip](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#rip) the vertex and for a new one.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *At Last* or *At First* [Merging](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html#merging-vertices), if you placed a vertex but wanted it to connect to a vertex already on the model, you can select the two vertices and merge them at the location of the "Good" vertex.
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> [vertex slide](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#vertex-slide), will let you slide the selected vertex along an edge.

Another tool that adds edges is [Vertex Connect](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/vertex_connect.html), it works by adding edges in a straight line between selected vertices.

Comment: Guess this is the closest I'll get. Thanks!